# Console.log doesn't work, devtools console shows no errors

Tags: javascript, debugging, console, google-chrome-devtools

A bunch of code isn't working and I'm trying to identify where the problem lies but `console.log()` isn't logging any results in Chrome Dev tools, am I doing it correctly?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       $('section').each(function(){
            var id='#'+$(this).attr('id'),
                off=$(id).offset().top,
                hei=$(id).height(),
                winscroll=$(window).scrollTop(),
                dif=hei+off-($(window).height());

            if (winscroll >= off && winscroll<=dif) {
                console.log('first broken');
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('abs').addClass('fix');
            } else if (winscroll > dif){
                console.log('second broken');
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('fix').addClass('abs');
            } else {
                console.log('third broken');
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('fix abs');
            }   });
        });
```

**EDIT FULL CODE ADDED**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // If a browser supports 3D transforms use the fancy menu if it doesn't, use standard accordion menu instead
    if($('html').hasClass('csstransforms3d')){

        $( "#mp-menu" ).removeClass( "snap-drawers" ).addClass( "mp-menu" );

        $('nav ul li ul').css('border-bottom','1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .05)');
        $('nav ul li ul').css('background','none');

        // Insert elements where necessary to create the right structure
        $('#mp-menu').wrapInner('<div class="mp-level" />');
        $('#mp-menu').find('li > ul').wrap('<div class="mp-level" />');

        $("#mp-menu ul li .mp-level").prepend(function () {
            return '<span class="menu-title">' + $(this).prev().text() + '</span> <a class="ico mp-back" href="#">Back</a>';
        });

        // load in necessary JS files
        $.getScript('http://176.32.230.2/baodev.com/cjo/wp-content/themes/CJO/js/multi-level-menu.js');

    } else {

        // load in necessary JS files
        $.getScript( "http://176.32.230.2/baodev.com/cjo/wp-content/themes/CJO/js/jquery.navgoco.min.js", function() {
            $("#demo1").navgoco({accordion: true});
        });

        $.getScript( "http://176.32.230.2/baodev.com/cjo/wp-content/themes/CJO/js/snap.min.js", function() {

            // Snapper settings     
            var snapper = new Snap({
              element: document.getElementById('scroller'),
              disable: 'right',
              maxPosition: 291
            });

            var addEvent = function addEvent(element, eventName, func) {
                if (element.addEventListener) {
                return element.addEventListener(eventName, func, false);
              } else if (element.attachEvent) {
                  return element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, func);
              }
            };

            // Toggle button
            addEvent(document.getElementById('trigger'), 'click', function(){
                if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
                    snapper.close();
                    $( ".menu-trigger" ).removeClass( "active" );
                } else {
                    snapper.open('left');
                    $( ".menu-trigger" ).addClass( "active" );
                }
            });

            addEvent(document.getElementById('scroller'), 'click', function(){
                if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
                    $( ".menu-trigger" ).removeClass( "active" );
                }
            });

            /* Prevent Safari opening links when viewing as a Mobile App */
            (function (a, b, c) {
              if(c in b && b[c]) {
                  var d, e = a.location,
                      f = /^(a|html)$/i;
                  a.addEventListener("click", function (a) {
                      d = a.target;
                      while(!f.test(d.nodeName)) d = d.parentNode;
                      "href" in d && (d.href.indexOf("http") || ~d.href.indexOf(e.host)) && (a.preventDefault(), e.href = d.href)
                  }, !1)
              }
            })(document, window.navigator, "standalone");

        });

    } // end if

    fitHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('section').each(function(){
            var id='#'+$(this).attr('id'),
                off=$(id).offset().top,
                hei=$(id).height(),
                winscroll=$(window).scrollTop(),
                dif=hei+off-($(window).height());

           console.log('msj');

            if (winscroll >= off && winscroll<=dif) {
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('abs').addClass('fix');
            } else if (winscroll > dif){
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('fix').addClass('abs');
            } else {
                $(id+' .sticky').removeClass('fix abs');
            }
        });
     });

});

// Trigger FitHeight on browser resize
$(window).resize(fitHeight);
```

**EDIT**

Some bits of the full code (above) refer to other JS files and code returns no errors when run with these files present. After troubleshooting I see the console message before the scroll function but I do not see the console message within the scroll function.

```
fitHeight();

    console.log('About to bind scroll effects'); // I SEE THIS MESSAGE

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        console.log("scroll bound, now loop through sections"); //BUT NOT THIS ONE

        $('section').each(function(){
```

Comment: rarely some strange error happens and restarting browser helps.

Comment: @ViliusL I wish it were that simple

Comment: You may have used the filter function in the console which will hide anything that doesn't match your query. Remove the query and your messages will display.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid on this but let this be a lesson to everyone...Make sure you target the right selector!

Basically the console wasn't logging anything because this particular code snippet was attempting to grab the scrolling area of my window, when in fact my code was setup differently to scroll an entire DIV instead. As soon as I changed:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
```

to this:

```
$('#scroller').scroll(function() {
```

The console started logging the correct messages.

Answer (score 136):

In my case, all console messages were not showing because I had left a string in the "filter" textbox.

Remove the filter it by clicking the X as shown:

[image]

Comment: this. fortunately or unfortunately, if once you set a filter on developer console of a tab, the filter will continues to be effective in consecutive tabs and its console.

Comment: Facepalm! I typed in something in the filter box few days ago.  And it killed 1hr today until I saw this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good heavens! Why does the filter value persist across not just tabs and consoles, but also closed / reopened instances?

Comment: shocks, thank you for solving my problem (face palm) `[+1]`

Answer (score 89):

Sounds like you've either hidden JavaScript logs or specified that you only want to see Errors or Warnings. Open Chrome's Developer Tools and go to the Console tab. At the bottom you want to ensure that JavaScript is ticked and also ensure that you have "All", "Logs" or "Debug" selected.

[image: Example Screenshot]

In the image above I have JavaScript, Network, Logging, CSS and Other ticked and "All" selected.

---

Another potential problem could be that your `$(window).scroll()` function isn't wrapped within a `.ready()` function (as documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

When pasting your code into JSFiddle and giving some dummy content, your code works perfectly fine: [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXwuN/).

---

### Edit:

The question was edited. The new code given throws two errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: fitHeight is not defined
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Because of this, the code stops execution prior to reaching any `console.log` call.

Comment: I thought that but I have everything checked and visible.

Comment: @egr103 please see my modified answer. :)

Comment: It's already within a .ready(). Not sure what the hell is going on, I've updated my code in full in my question.

Comment: @egr103 your full code throws two errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: fitHeight is not defined` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`.

Comment: These errors refer to the files that aren't loaded with this code in the question and work fine when present. No errors are seen in the log. If I put a log message before the scroll function and after ther other pieces of unrelated code, the message appears but no messages appear within the scroll function itself

Comment: @egr103 possibly silly question, but are you actually scrolling the page?

Comment: In Chrome if you don't have the developer tools opened when loading the site, you won't get any log output.

Comment: I just bumped in this question while searching for a similar problem with Firefox developer tools. It turns out that Console.log() does not write in the JS section but in the Logging section.

Comment: In Chrome 91.0.4472.124 the bottom menu in the first part of the answer doesn't exist.

Comment: wasted my 2 hours checking the output until I reached here, and turned it 'on' in chrome.. 

Don't know for what reason I had turned it off earlier!! to confuse my slef! Thanks..

Comment: This question ate my week, and this answer helped me even after 10 years. Thankyou.

Answer (score 12):

Click on the restore button. `console.log` will start to work.

[image]

Comment: It worked... but... why??? Obviously something out of whack.

Answer (score 7):

## 2021 solution

- open developer tools
- navigate to "console"
- most likely "Verbose" is not ticked, so activate it

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It was because I had turned off "Logs" in the list of boxes earlier. [image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was developing a Polymer WebComponent, which is included using `<link rel="import">` into the main HTML document. Turns out that the WebComponent HTML file was being cached for some reason, even though I had changed it since the cached version.

To solve it I opened the Developer Console (in Chrome), right clicked on the reload arrow next to the URL bar and selected "Empty cache and hard reload" - problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere `console.log` had been overridden in a js file somewhere (that I haven't been able to locate).

But I could test by putting `console.log` in the console and I only got an empty function: `f{}`

I added this to the top of my own js file to correct it (absolute hack, but worked for me):

```
var console = window.console;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to select right option to show the log messages from the option provided in left side under the console tab. You can refer the screen shot.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just had a same issue of none of my console message showing. It was simply because I was using the new Edge (Chromium based) browser on Windows 10. It does not show my console messages whereas Chrome does. I guessed it was an issue with Edge because I had another odd issue with Edge because it treated strings with single quotes and double quotes differently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a more pragmatic approach to the question of "doing it correctly".

```
console.log("about to bind scroll fx");

$(window).scroll(function() {

       console.log("scroll bound, loop through div's");

       $('div').each(function(){
```

If both of those `log`s output correctly, then its likely the problem exists in your var declaration.  To debug that, consider breaking it out into several lines:

```
var id='#'+$(this).attr('id');

console.log(id);

var off=$(id).offset().top;
var hei=$(id).height();
var winscroll=$(window).scrollTop();
var dif=hei+off-($(window).height());
```

By doing this, at least during debugging, you may find that the var `id` is undefined, causing errors throughout the rest of the code.  Is it possible some of your `div` tags do not have id's?

Comment: woah, you just added a lot more code samples... this answer may be invalid.

Comment: Thanks. Well, the line: console.log("about to bind scroll fx"); is outputted but the other log message doesn't output. What does this mean?

Comment: That likely indicates you haven't scrolled or its not firing the scroll function. do you get other javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

As a complete new at javascript, I just had the same problem on my side here. The mistake I did, was that I used:

```
<script type="text.javascript">
  console.log("bla bla bla");
</script>
```

instead of:

```
<script>
  console.log("bla bla bla");
</script>
```

using the

> type="text.javascript"

had the result of not producing the log in the console.

Comment: please make it correct <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by [`console.groupCollapsed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/groupCollapsed).

And collapsed messages don't get detected by *ctrl+f* apparently.

Maintaining unfamiliar code is scary sometimes...

It even collapsed the exception message, absence of which made me put those `console.log`s in the first place ^_^

Answer (score 0):

if using $ parameter in console.log within html, then single quotes(') and double quotes("") will not work.

use quotes like (` `)

example:
console.log(`${address}`);

This will help when using the `$` parameter and anyone facing issues in console.log.