# console.log in handleSubmit after event.preventDefault() not appear

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm new on next js

I create a simple form submission, after submit button is clicked I want to console.log inside handleSubmit function but the console.log is not executed.

This is my pages/index.tsx with handleSubmit function

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    async function handleSubmit(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault()
        console.log('index#log1')//<- this is not executed
Router.push('/dashboard')//it's executed
    }
}
  return (
    <>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
          integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <title>Simple Login Page</title>
      </head>

      <div
        className="min-h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-gray-100"
      >
        <div
          className="
          flex flex-col
          bg-white
          shadow-md
          px-4
          sm:px-6
          md:px-8
          lg:px-10
          py-8
          rounded-3xl
          w-50
          max-w-md
        "
        >
          <div className="font-medium self-center text-xl sm:text-3xl text-gray-800">
            Welcome Back
          </div>
          <div className="mt-4 self-center text-xl sm:text-sm text-gray-800">
            Enter your credentials to access your account
          </div>

          <div className="mt-10">
            {/* <form action="#"> */}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="flex flex-col mb-5">
                <label
                  htmlFor="email"
                  className="mb-1 text-xs tracking-wide text-gray-600"
                >E-Mail Address:</label
                >
                <div className="relative">
                  <div
                    className="
                    inline-flex
                    items-center
                    justify-center
                    absolute
                    left-0
                    top-0
                    h-full
                    w-10
                    text-gray-400
                  "
                  >
                    <i className="fas fa-at text-blue-500"></i>
                  </div>

                  <input
                    id="email"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    className="
                    text-sm
                    placeholder-gray-500
                    pl-10
                    pr-4
                    rounded-2xl
                    border border-gray-400
                    w-full
                    py-2
                    focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400
                  "
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col mb-6">
                <label
                  htmlFor="password"
                  className="mb-1 text-xs sm:text-sm tracking-wide text-gray-600"
                >Password:</label
                >
                <div className="relative">
                  <div
                    className="
                    inline-flex
                    items-center
                    justify-center
                    absolute
                    left-0
                    top-0
                    h-full
                    w-10
                    text-gray-400
                  "
                  >
                    <span>
                      <i className="fas fa-lock text-blue-500"></i>
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <input
                    id="password"
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    className="
                    text-sm
                    placeholder-gray-500
                    pl-10
                    pr-4
                    rounded-2xl
                    border border-gray-400
                    w-full
                    py-2
                    focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400
                  "
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="flex w-full">
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="
                  flex
                  mt-2
                  items-center
                  justify-center
                  focus:outline-none
                  text-white text-sm
                  sm:text-base
                  bg-blue-500
                  hover:bg-blue-600
                  rounded-2xl
                  py-2
                  w-full
                  transition
                  duration-150
                  ease-in
                "
                >
                  <span className="mr-2 uppercase">Sign In</span>
                  <span>
                    <svg
                      className="h-6 w-6"
                      fill="none"
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      strokeWidth="2"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      stroke="currentColor"
                    >
                      <path
                        d="M13 9l3 3m0 0l-3 3m3-3H8m13 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-6">
          <a
            href="#"
            target="_blank"
            className="
            inline-flex
            items-center
            text-gray-700
            font-medium
            text-xs text-center
          "
          >
            <span className="ml-2"
            >You don't have an account?
              <a
                href="#"
                className="text-xs ml-2 text-blue-500 font-semibold"
              >Register now</a
              ></span
            >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

It's very simple but I don't know why no log appears on the terminal, while the function is properly executed. I know it's executed because after form submission the page is redirected to /dashboard

Comment: The `console.log` is executing, but before you see it, the '/dashboard' page comes in and the console is cleared, so you don't see it! To confirm this, comment the line `Router.push('/dashboard')`. Then you can see the log;

Comment: @MuhammedRahif tried without router.push but nothing appears

Comment: I don't think that only one line is not executing. Maybe it's other problems, something like: you're disabled the 'logs' in browser (developer options)

Comment: @MuhammedRahif thank you, it answered my question. Previously I'm looking for the output on the visual studio code terminal, not on the browser console. Is it really like that to view logs is not on the visual studio code terminal but on the console browser? sorry I'm pretty new on next js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### I don't think that only one line is not executing. Maybe it's other problems, something like: [*You're disabled the 'logs' in browser (developer options).*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19662083/14781260)

---

*- Reposted comment*