# Why can loop an JAVASCRIPT object array

Tags: javascript

Why I can't loop on 'data' ?

```js
data = [{type: 'a', data: 'xyz'}, {type: 'a', data: 'xyz'}, {type: 'a', data: 'xyz'}];

for (i in data) {
  console.log('one line');
}
```

0 results, but data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDJxb.png), data[2] has data...

[image]

Comment: Did you use `i` anywhere else in the scope? try using a var in front of the i like this: `for (var i in data) {}`

Comment: Check if you don't have a filter or you've filtered out info messages.

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of: [Console.log not working at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19662018) or [In Firefox, console.log is not showing anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15633404)

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ, shame on me . That drove me crazy, I did a rage post here to see what could go wrong, you fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely loop any kind of array in javascript I'll only provide one way to loop and I believe it is the most easier one for beginners:

```js
const data = [{},{},{}]
data.map((object)=>console.log(object)) // object would be each object of your data array.
```

Comment: `map` is not what you want to use if you're not returning anything. Did you mean `forEach`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how it can be inferred from the question that the OP is a beginner, especially after the resolution achieved in the comments.

Comment: It is still a way to loop in javascript and it is still a valid way of looping. sorry but I don't understand why we'll keep talking about this, have a nice day! thanks.

Comment: @MoussaBistami - it is a loop but its not the correct one. The goal of this service is to help people learn, and so it's important that the instruction align with _best practices_. There was no mention of returning values or altering arrays so `map` isn't the right tool for the job

Answer (score -1):

try using `for of`

```
for (i of data) {
 console.log(i);
}

output:

{ type: 'a', data: 'xyz' }
{ type: 'a', data: 'xyz' }
{ type: 'a', data: 'xyz' }
```

Comment: This would work why? Given that a regular `for` doesn't work for OP?